# How to have 2+ boxes slide down

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I have been reading tutorials from several different places like http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/ or http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/
and have been playing around with them but cant seem to figure out how I would be able to add more then just that one sliding box on the page. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption (from the first example link) is that instead of just having `#sidebar`  stay in view, you want to have another element scroll with the window as well (i.e. logged in user's details).

The easiest way would be to add this information to your existing scrolling element:

```
<ul id="sidebar">
    <li id="user-details">Name: John Doe<br/>Email: john.doe@gmail.com</li>  
    <!-- remaining links here --> 
</ul>
```

However, if you want to scroll two elements with the window:

```
<ul id="sidebar">
    <!-- sidebar links --> 
</ul>
<ul id="user-details">
    <!-- user details --> 
</ul>
```

It would just be a matter of animating both of their margin-top's inside the `$(window).scroll()` event handler:

**Edit**

The following code scrolls `#sidebar` until it reaches 2000px of scroll at which point it stops and scrolls `#user-details` until it reaches 4000px of scroll:

```
// constants for the scrolling
var offsetSidebar = $("#sidebar").offset();
var offsetUserDetails = $("#user-details").offset();

// on scroll of window
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scrollElement($("#sidebar"), offsetSidebar, 2000);
    scrollElement($("#user-details"), offsetUserDetails, 4000);
});

// handle the scrolling
function scrollElement(elem, offset, boundary){
    var currOffset = elem.offset();
    if(currOffset.top < boundary && $(window).scrollTop() < boundary){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            elem.stop().animate({marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top});
        } else {
            elem.stop().animate({marginTop: 0});
        }
    }
}
```

You can see it [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/c2DQm/2/).

Comment: I am sorry I guess I did not explain this well enough what I want is to have one box A follow you until it gets to a certain point. Now box a has stopped and box B will start following you until that gets to a certain point. Now box b has stopped and box c will start following you and so on and so on

Comment: That's still easy enough. You just have to setup boundary conditions for all your boxes to test against `$(window).scrollTop()`.  So for example, box A will follow until `$(window).scrollTop() > 2000`, box will follow until `$(window).scrollTop() > 4000` etc.  I've updated my example so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Can I make the boundary a class or id?

Comment: not directly if you want to use it to style the elements.  An id or class won't be recognized if it starts with a number.  You'd have to prefix it with a letter and then trim the letter off in your javascript.

Comment: can you show me an example? I think I understand but I wanna make sure.